# Udisks doesn't work after upgrade to ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mount, 15.10, udisks

If I mount a device from commandline as user I usually do something like `udisks --mount /dev/sdc1`. However since my upgrade from ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10 this command seems to be gone. A package called `udisks2` seems to be installed. Did the name of the command change? How to make it work again? Is there any alternative for mounting from commandline as user?